# I can't access to caller of jquery plugins method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery plugin like this:

```js
(function(e) {
    e.fn.dmHall = function(args) {
        var st = {
            push: 30,
            rtl: false,
        };

        e.extend(st, args);
        var main = e(this);

        e.fn.dmHall.hideThis() = function(args){
            this.hide();
        }

        $('#myelement').click(function(e){
            $(this).dmHall.hideThis();
        });
    }
})(jQuery)
```

However this not working and I cannot get `$('#myelement')` as caller of `hideThis()` method without set it as argument.

I want to create a submethod that can work like `hide()` or anything.

Comment: Why not just use `hide()`? I don't see the benefit of having a wrapper simply for a single method call.

Answer (score 0):

This code is for plugin file `dmHallThisHide` new function is added in jQuery plugin list:

```
(function(e, window, document, undefined) {

    e.fn.dmHallThisHide = function (args) {
        var st = {
            push: 30,
            rtl: false,
        };

        e.extend(st, args);
        var main = e(this);

        this.each(function(index, value) {//this.each is required as selector may get element array
            e(this).hide();
        });

    }

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

To call this plugin following code is required (it can be in a separate file):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(<<SELECTOR>>).dmHallThisHide();
});
```

Please check jQuery plugin boilerplage for more detailed version of jQuery plugin, link: https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate